# How do you navigate in code completion drop downs when using vscodevim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I try to use `hjkl` for navigation in VS code, but I get thrown off whenever a code completion drop down appears as I must use the arrow keys to navigate those. Is there any way around this? How do you do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+N: Move to the next option in the dropdown.
Ctrl+P: Move to the previous option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use control key with <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to move between autocomplete options.

Like <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will move to the next option. and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> will move to previous option.